# Getting KeyError when addressing one column for NaN replacement

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I'm getting a KeyError relating to one column when I am trying to reassign NaN as 0 when using pandas, and I wondered if anyone had any ideas how I could address this? I've attached my code so you can take a look.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
#import sklearn

#map 1
df1 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Normal/L4D2 Stats normal - c8m1 apartment.csv', header=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Adversarial/L4D2 Stats adversarial - c8m1 apartment.csv', header=0)
df3 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Helpful/L4D2 Stats helpful - c8m1 apartment.csv', header=0)
df4 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Neutral/L4D2 Stats neutral - c8m1 apartment.csv', header=0)
df5 = pd.read_csv('D:/Documents/Data Science/L4D2 Stats - No Mercy CSV files updated version/Random/L4D2 stats random - c8m1 apartment.csv', header=0)

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for list in df_list:
    df=list
    df.describe()
    df['Special Spawns'] = df['Special Spawns'].fillna(0)
    df['Population'] = df['Population'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 1 Health'] = df['Bot 1 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 2 Health'] = df['Bot 2 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 3 Health'] = df['Bot 3 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 4 Health'] = df['Bot 4 Health'].fillna(0)
    df['Incaps'] = df['Incaps'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 1 Intensity'] = df['Bot 1 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 2 Intensity'] = df['Bot 2 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 3 Intensity'] = df['Bot 3 Intensity'].fillna(0)
    df['Bot 4 Intensity'] = df['Bot 4 Intensity'].fillna(0)

    directsum_column = df["Population"] + df["Special Spawns"]
    df["Direct Involvement"] = directsum_column
    

    print(df)
```

If anyone has any ideas why it has issues with this one column I would appreciate any help.

Comment: which line is throwing the KeyError?  look at the stack trace

Comment: in general avoid using ```list``` as a variable name.  that is a python internal name and should not be clobbered in case you want to use it.  You can iterate the df_list via ```for df in df_list:``` and forego the ```list``` variable entirely

Comment: It's likely that one of the columns you're referencing does not exist. Look at the stack trace to find which one.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone! I've sussed out a workaround in manually labelling columns in pandas rather than trying to import the CSV column titles, which seems to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Also @AbbeGijly thank you for the heads up on not using list, I wasn't sure if I was taking the right approach and this has answered that for me as well. Wasn't aware of it's integral python properties. All corrected now :)